# php regex split string by [%%%]

Tags: php, regex

Hi I need a `preg_split` regex that will split a string at substrings in square brackets.

This example input:

```
$string = 'I have a string containing [substrings] in [brackets].';
```

should provide this array output:

```
[0]= 'I have a string containing '
[1]= '[substrings]'
[2]= ' in '
[3]= '[brackets]'
[4]= '.'
```

Comment: @John, don't understand your question. Can u be more clear. Also it is a good habit to put a bit code to see what you tried.

Comment: Could you give more examples of what these %'s might be? and might not be?

Comment: Hm, do you mean a _literal_ `[` & `]` with anything in between? (I suspect much of the confusion might stem from this...)

Comment: so possibly something like... $result = preg_split('/\\s*\\[[^\\]]{3,}\\]\\s*/',$string) which will also take into account whitespace either side of the []'s or more like preg_split('/(\\[|\\])/',$string) to get your above array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**After reading your revised question:**

This might be what you want:

```
$string = 'I have a string containing [substrings] in [brackets].';
preg_split('/(\[.*?\])/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

You should get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I have a string containing 
    [1] => [substrings]
    [2] =>  in 
    [3] => [brackets]
    [4] => .
)
```

**Original answer:**

```
preg_split('/%+/i', 'ot limited to 3 %%% so it can be %%%% or % or %%%%%, etc Tha');
```

You should get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ot limited to 3 
    [1] =>  so it can be 
    [2] =>  or 
    [3] =>  or 
    [4] => , etc Tha
)
```

Or if you want a mimimum of 3 then try:

```
preg_split('/%%%+/i', 'Not limited to 3 %%% so it can be %%%% or % or %%%%%, etc Tha');
```

### Have a go at http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$array = preg_split('/(\[.*?\])/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Dis you mean `preg_split('/(\[.*?\])/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

Comment: you need the brackets `()` too.