# regex split by %%%%%%[%%%%][%%%%%%%%] and lose the brackets

Tags: php, regex, string

Like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246269/php-regex-split-string-by) I need to split on brackets.

But I also need to lose the brackets..

```
%%%%%%[%%%%][%%%%%%%%]
```

into:

```
array {
[0] -> %%%%%%
[1] -> %%%%
[2] -> %%%%%%%%
}
```

Comment: `preg_split('/(\[.*?\])/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);` lose the last argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
preg_split('/[[\]]+/', $str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

http://www.ideone.com/S0ijT

Answer (score 2):

This is so easy that you can even get away with match I think :

```
preg_match_all('/[^[\]]+/', $subject, $result);
$result = $result[0];
```

$result will have all your matches.