# RegEx for split text on string .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246269/php-regex-split-string-by) answer for my question, but it for PHP. Perhaps there is an analogue for .NET? I know about `Split` method, but I don't understand how to save text outside my tags `<@any_text@>`, and I need a regular expression (by the condition of the task).

For example:

```
string: aaa<@bbb@>aaa<@bb@>c

list: aaa
      <@bbb@>
      aaa
      <@bb@>
      c
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have passing test. It wasn't hard to find it on web and it would be definitely faster and better for you - try first finding solution yourself, trying some code, and then ask a question. This way you will actually learn something.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    string source = "aaa<@bbb@>aaa<@bb@>c";
    Regex r = new Regex("(<@.+?@>)");

    string[] result = r.Split(source);
    Assert.AreEqual(5, result.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always have try to find solution, but regexes so complicated for me

Comment: Cool. Regexes should not be overused but sometimes they come very handy. It's worth to learn a thing or two about them. If this or any other answer helped you - upvote it and mark it as an answer. We all like reputation ;)

Comment: I'd like to vote up,  but I have reputation low than 15. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = @"aaa<@bbb@>aaa<@bb@>c";
var list = Regex.Matches(input, @"\<.+?\>|[^\<].+?[^\>]|.+?")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Even though your solution is correct - I would prefer my - simpler and done the way it was designed for. However I like your regular expression. I'll never learn how to read them quickly ;)

Comment: @Pako I can't also read my own regex after a single day. therefore I mostly try to avoid using  regex :) For this question I would simply use **`input.Split(new char[] { '<', '>' });`** then add `<` and `>`